# How to find coherent datetime ranges in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Data consists of rows containing a Length/Duration in Minutes, a Begin & EndTime. The precision is 1min (or larger).

the table looks something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE public."TimeSeries" (
    "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "BeginTime" timestamptz NOT NULL,
    "EndTime" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01 00:00:00' :: timestamp without time zone,
    "LengthMin" int4 NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO public."TimeSeries" ("Id","BeginTime","LengthMin","EndTime") VALUES
     ('ecabcd8d-3129-4128-b126-a4e1abcd49c9'::uuid,'2021-11-16 11:45:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 11:46:00.000'),
     ('e5abcd70-5125-412b-9128-93ecabcdcba9'::uuid,'2021-11-16 11:46:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 11:47:00.000'),
     ('03abcdb8-8129-4124-b126-f5bbabcd7157'::uuid,'2021-11-16 11:47:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 11:48:00.000'),
     ('54abcdcc-6129-4126-912b-34b2abcde19a'::uuid,'2021-11-16 11:50:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 11:51:00.000'),
     ('77abcd28-212f-4122-912f-5060abcd2aa0'::uuid,'2021-11-16 11:51:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 11:52:00.000'),
     ('8babcdd1-f12a-4124-9128-2529abcda136'::uuid,'2021-11-16 11:52:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 11:53:00.000'),
     ('8aabcd94-9129-4121-b12c-1ebfabcd06b8'::uuid,'2021-11-16 12:35:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 12:36:00.000'),
     ('96abcd04-b12e-4122-b12b-4dc2abcdcee4'::uuid,'2021-11-16 12:40:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 12:41:00.000'),
     ('42abcd4a-f129-412c-9124-41b3abcd3ca3'::uuid,'2021-11-16 12:44:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 12:45:00.000'),
     ('beabcd8f-c12f-4126-a12b-0a37abcdd0bb'::uuid,'2021-11-16 12:49:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 12:50:00.000'),
     ('b8abcd79-d12c-4120-912f-754fabcdd220'::uuid,'2021-11-16 12:50:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 12:51:00.000'),
     ('c3abcd08-e121-4127-b125-4e70abcd5756'::uuid,'2021-11-16 12:59:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 13:00:00.000'),
     ('65abcdbe-7121-412a-a12c-1f68abcd94eb'::uuid,'2021-11-16 13:00:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 13:01:00.000'),
     ('f5abcd38-9122-412c-b12f-957fabcd79b5'::uuid,'2021-11-16 13:05:00.000',1,'2021-11-16 13:06:00.000');
```

The code I came up with looks something like that:
( http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fdda3/1 )

```
SELECT
    "BeginTime" = lag("EndTime") OVER (
        ORDER BY
            "BeginTime"
    ) AS "isInSeries",
    *
FROM
    "TimeSeries"
WHERE
    "LengthMin" = 1
ORDER BY
    "BeginTime"
```

The result:

```
 
    | isInSeries |                                   Id |            BeginTime |              EndTime | LengthMin |
    |------------|--------------------------------------|----------------------|----------------------|-----------|
    |     (null) | ecabcd8d-3129-4128-b126-a4e1abcd49c9 | 2021-11-16T11:45:00Z | 2021-11-16T11:46:00Z |         1 |
    |       true | e5abcd70-5125-412b-9128-93ecabcdcba9 | 2021-11-16T11:46:00Z | 2021-11-16T11:47:00Z |         1 |
    |       true | 03abcdb8-8129-4124-b126-f5bbabcd7157 | 2021-11-16T11:47:00Z | 2021-11-16T11:48:00Z |         1 |
    |      false | 54abcdcc-6129-4126-912b-34b2abcde19a | 2021-11-16T11:50:00Z | 2021-11-16T11:51:00Z |         1 |
    |       true | 77abcd28-212f-4122-912f-5060abcd2aa0 | 2021-11-16T11:51:00Z | 2021-11-16T11:52:00Z |         1 |
    |       true | 8babcdd1-f12a-4124-9128-2529abcda136 | 2021-11-16T11:52:00Z | 2021-11-16T11:53:00Z |         1 |
    |      false | 8aabcd94-9129-4121-b12c-1ebfabcd06b8 | 2021-11-16T12:35:00Z | 2021-11-16T12:36:00Z |         1 |
    |      false | 96abcd04-b12e-4122-b12b-4dc2abcdcee4 | 2021-11-16T12:40:00Z | 2021-11-16T12:41:00Z |         1 |
    |      false | 42abcd4a-f129-412c-9124-41b3abcd3ca3 | 2021-11-16T12:44:00Z | 2021-11-16T12:45:00Z |         1 |
    |      false | beabcd8f-c12f-4126-a12b-0a37abcdd0bb | 2021-11-16T12:49:00Z | 2021-11-16T12:50:00Z |         1 |
    |       true | b8abcd79-d12c-4120-912f-754fabcdd220 | 2021-11-16T12:50:00Z | 2021-11-16T12:51:00Z |         1 |
    |      false | c3abcd08-e121-4127-b125-4e70abcd5756 | 2021-11-16T12:59:00Z | 2021-11-16T13:00:00Z |         1 |
    |       true | 65abcdbe-7121-412a-a12c-1f68abcd94eb | 2021-11-16T13:00:00Z | 2021-11-16T13:01:00Z |         1 |
    |      false | f5abcd38-9122-412c-b12f-957fabcd79b5 | 2021-11-16T13:05:00Z | 2021-11-16T13:06:00Z |         1 |
```

I'm trying to compare `BeginTime = lag(EndTime)` however then I am not able to connect rows which are in the same series. Then I just know that the row before is in the same series.

The expected result should look something like this:

```
|          SeriesBegin | cnt |                  min |                  max |            delta |
|----------------------|-----|----------------------|----------------------|------------------|
| 2021-11-16T11:45:00Z |   3 | 2021-11-16T11:45:00Z | 2021-11-16T11:48:00Z | 3 mins 0.00 secs |
| 2021-11-16T11:50:00Z |   3 | 2021-11-16T11:50:00Z | 2021-11-16T11:53:00Z | 3 mins 0.00 secs |
| 2021-11-16T12:35:00Z |   1 | 2021-11-16T12:35:00Z | 2021-11-16T12:36:00Z | 1 mins 0.00 secs |
| 2021-11-16T12:40:00Z |   1 | 2021-11-16T12:40:00Z | 2021-11-16T12:41:00Z | 1 mins 0.00 secs |
| 2021-11-16T12:44:00Z |   1 | 2021-11-16T12:44:00Z | 2021-11-16T12:45:00Z | 1 mins 0.00 secs |
| 2021-11-16T12:49:00Z |   2 | 2021-11-16T12:49:00Z | 2021-11-16T12:51:00Z | 2 mins 0.00 secs |
| 2021-11-16T12:59:00Z |   2 | 2021-11-16T12:59:00Z | 2021-11-16T13:01:00Z | 2 mins 0.00 secs |
| 2021-11-16T13:05:00Z |   1 | 2021-11-16T13:05:00Z | 2021-11-16T13:06:00Z | 1 mins 0.00 secs |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Gaps & Islands problem. You can use the standard solution for it, that is assigning a number to each "island". For example:

```
select
  count(*) as cnt,
  min("BeginTime") as begin_time,
  max("EndTime") as end_time,
  max("EndTime") - min("BeginTime") as delta
from (
  select *, sum(inc) over(order by "BeginTime") as grp
  from (
    SELECT *,
      case when "BeginTime" = lag("EndTime") OVER (ORDER BY "BeginTime") then 0 else 1 end as inc
    FROM "TimeSeries"
    WHERE   "LengthMin" = 1
  ) x
) y
group by grp
order by begin_time
```

Result:

```
 cnt  begin_time            end_time              delta                                          
 ---- --------------------- --------------------- ---------------------------------------------- 
 3    2021-11-16T11:45:00Z  2021-11-16T11:48:00Z  0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 3 mins 0.00 secs 
 3    2021-11-16T11:50:00Z  2021-11-16T11:53:00Z  0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 3 mins 0.00 secs 
 1    2021-11-16T12:35:00Z  2021-11-16T12:36:00Z  0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 0.00 secs 
 1    2021-11-16T12:40:00Z  2021-11-16T12:41:00Z  0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 0.00 secs 
 1    2021-11-16T12:44:00Z  2021-11-16T12:45:00Z  0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 0.00 secs 
 2    2021-11-16T12:49:00Z  2021-11-16T12:51:00Z  0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 2 mins 0.00 secs 
 2    2021-11-16T12:59:00Z  2021-11-16T13:01:00Z  0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 2 mins 0.00 secs 
 1    2021-11-16T13:05:00Z  2021-11-16T13:06:00Z  0 years 0 mons 0 days 0 hours 1 mins 0.00 secs
```

See running example at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/fdda3/8).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is working great and also easily extendable to also work with duplicates